# Loading a method using a string variable

Tags: php, oop

How can i work with something like:

```
$parameter = "get_something()";

$value = $this->method->$parameter;
```

I'm getting the error "undefined property $get_something()" (note the $).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use

```
$name = "get_something";
$value = $this->method->$name();
```

instead